# is changed function in sequelize like isModified in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

[mongoose isModified function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dzEp.png)In a hook I want to confirm whether a password has changed before executing encryption process. Mongoose has a function "isModified" and I believe Sequelize's "changed" function servers the same purpose.

I cannot get the "changed" function to work. I am looking for an example of how it is used.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how `changed()` works in the [official documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-method-changed)

```js
const mdl = await MyModel.findOne();
mdl.myJsonField.a = 1;
console.log(mdl.changed()) => false
await mdl.save(); // this will not save anything
mdl.changed('myJsonField', true);
console.log(mdl.changed()) => ['myJsonField']
await mdl.save(); // will save
```

Keep in mind that changes are detected for the top-level fields and only for changes that were made since the last `save` call.

Comment: u know why mdl.save(); will not save anything?

Comment: If you change some props in the JSON fields object then `save` will not track them at all. I suppose Sequelize tracks changes of the whole field value only. In the case of the JSON field, this would be replacing the whole object value.

Comment: hooks: {
                afterValidate: async function (user, next)  {
                    if (!user.changed("password")) { 
                        next()
                    }
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
                }
            }, can u tell me what is wrong in this?because it throws me an error saying next is not  a function. whenever i try to reset password it rehash it. please, help me here. i am totally stuck. thank u.

Comment: Please move to a separate question and give a link to it here if you want me to look at it